# Loss in Deep Q-Learning becomes zero

Tags: conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, loss-functions

My problem in training a Deep Q-Network is that the mean squared error (MSE) loss becomes zero.

I am using the Adam optimiser on a CNN. Can you give me a hint in which direction to look? How is that even possible?

Comment: MSE of near zero does not necessarily mean failure to learn in reinforcement-learning. What you have explained so far, the fault could be anything at all, from problem definition to some minor detail of your implementation. Please give more details of what you are attempting, and what the estimated Q function looks like . . . does it seem to predict realistic action values? Does the agent perform optimally, or is it stuck unable to learn?

Comment: Thanks Neil Slater for the useful comments. It was indeed a problem of the implementation, since I was loading my weights from model checkpoint, but was not remembering the loss I had and initialised it with zero and it stayed there. The agent was indeed making not really sensible moves, so it still has to learn.

Answer (score 4):

The training loss becomes zero when your model becomes "perfect" at giving predictions for the training data. However, it is the **validation loss**, i.e., the loss on data that were not used for training, that tells you how good the model really is.

Unless the validation error is also low, you are experiencing **overfitting**. In that case search for some of many available methods to perform neural network **regularization**. For a comprehensive overview of regularization methods you can refer to my article [Regularization for Deep Learning: A Taxonomy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10686).